# Swift ¿Es posible organizar las fotos que capturas en carpetas?

Tags: swift

Necesito hacer una app en donde puedas seleccionar categorías después actives la cámara y todas las fotos que se tomen se guarden en una carpeta con el nombre de esa categoría, es decir, si seleccionas la categoría "A" las fotos que tomes se guarden dentro de una carpeta llamada "A", después seleccionas categoría "B" pero a su vez seleccionas una subcategoria "B1" entonces todo lo que comiences a tomar se guarden en una carpeta "B1" pero que ésta a su vez esta dentro de una carpeta principal "B" (B/B1/mifoto.jpg) y así dependiendo de la categoría y subcategorias seleccionadas, para que al finalizar con todas las categorías el usuario pueda conectar su teléfono a una computadora y copie todas sus fotos ya organizadas. ¿es posible hacer algo así en Swift(iOS)? he buscado por todos lados y no encuentro nada parecido, entonces temo que no sea posible y solo se te permita crear un álbum donde guardes las fotos que tomas con tu App.

Comment: Guardar en carpetas dentro de tu App o en las carpetas de Fotos?

Comment: De prefencia en misma de la App pero si la única opción es en la galería de fotos no hay problema tampoco, ¿si existe forma de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente función para crear una carpeta y almacenar ahí las fotos de la cámara.

Puedes enviar como parámetro el nombre de la carpeta que quieras crear.

```
func saveImage(imageName: String){
        var isObjCBool: ObjCBool = true
        let mainPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0];
        let folderPath = mainPath + "/Medicinas/"//Aquí el nombre tu carpeta. La puedes enviar como parámetro.
        
        let existFile = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: folderPath, isDirectory: &isObjCBool)
        if !existFile {
            do {
                try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: folderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let imageName = "\(imageName).png"
        let imageUrl = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Medicinas/\(imageName)")
        if let image = self.viewPhoto.image {
            do {
                let data = image.lowestQualityJPEGNSData//Esta es una función para bajar la calidad de la foto para que no ocupe mucho espacio. Puedes utilizar la tuya
                try data.write(to: imageUrl)
            } catch {
                print("No se pudo guardar", error)
            }
        }
```

En el finder te vas a tu iPhone y en Files te aparece la carpeta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿El nombre de imagen que recibe este método es el nombre temporal de la imagen capturada o el nombre final que recibe cuando se guarda? Independientemente de eso respondiste a mi pregunta de que si es posible organizar las fotos hechas en carpetas dentro de un iphone. Gracias.

Comment: Que bueno. Es el nombre final, yo estoy enviando algo así: `"Nombre"+fecha` para formar un nombre único.